# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '{' (at style.css:1:4)

Tags: css, syntax, syntax-error

I'm trying to use a stylesheet. However, I keep getting this error:
"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '{' (at style.css:1:4)"

[My html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P7deC.png)

[My css](https://i.stack.imgur.com/16X2m.png)

I've tried moving the '{' to the next line (which worked) but then it says:
"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':' (at style.css:3:11)"

Comment: Not sure if this is relevant, but I'm using Replit.

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: Welcome! Can you please provide a [mre]? See [ask] for further guidance. Would it be possible for you to provide a [Stack Snippet](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/11107541)? Note: Stack Snippets are preferred over links to external repros for reasons explained in [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your **HTML** use `<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css">` instead.
CSS Styles are not scripts

Answer (score 0):

```
In your html put all <script> tags inside the <head> tag as follows:

<head>
  <link src="../css/style.css" rel="stylesheet"></link>
  <script src="[ENTER JQUERY URL HERE]"></script>
  <script src="[ENTER ANOTHER URL HERE]"></script>
</head>
```